# Load lists & dictionaries into memory at OS startup for later reference in VBA macros

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote several VBA macros respectively for Excel, Word, PowerPoint and Outlook (the mail editor) to do replacement according to word/character pairs stored in an Excel file.

Currently each Office application has to load the pairs from the same Excel file on its own (either at application startup or when the replacement sub is called). Is it possible to read the pairs into memory at OS startup, and make them:

1. accessible from all macros
2. reloadable in case the pairs are modified?

If that's difficult, since my Outlook starts along with the OS and will keep running anyway, is it possible to look up lists and dictionaries generated in Outlook from macros in other Office applications?

My current code for loading the pairs at the startup of Outlook:

```
Dim oDic_term As Object, term_num As Integer, key_term As String

Private Sub Application_Startup()

UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = "Loading Term List"
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

Dim lexiconfile, lexicon As String, i As Integer

lexicon = "D:\Translation Toolkit\Translation Toolkit Lexicon.xlsx"
lexiconfile = "Translation Toolkit Lexicon.xlsx"

Dim exlapp As New Excel.Application

exlapp.Workbooks.Open FileName:=lexicon, ReadOnly:=True

Set oDic_term = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With exlapp.Workbooks(lexiconfile).Worksheets("Word Pairs")

    term_num = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ReDim key_term(term_num) As String

    For i = .UsedRange.Row To (.UsedRange.Row + term_num - 1)

        key_term(i - .UsedRange.Row + 1) = .Range("A" & i).Value

        oDic_term.Item(.Range("A" & i).Value) = .Range("B" & i).Value

    Next

End With

exlapp.Workbooks(lexiconfile).Close

exlapp.Quit

UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: @vba4all Thanks for your reply. It seems that Workbook_Open() can be used to make Excel do something when started. But I can't see how I can do what I want to with it. Could you please elaborate a little bit on that?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at OS startup, but should be possible at application startup. An Add-in for each application can be configured to run procedures at startup. Since you are doing this in Excel, Word, PPT, and Outlook, you may be interested in creating a COM Add-in, which would be a single Add-in that can be applied to ALL office applications. (NB: I have never actually created a COM add-in)

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for your information! The problem with an Add-in: In many cases I start the application only to quickly skim the file without doing any replacement, however, an Add-in pre-loading around 1000 word pairs would make that process much slower. In contrast, most of the time I only have to start the OS once per day, I do not mind if that takes a bit longer time.

Comment: How do you know this? Have you tested it for performance? Assuming this is all done in memory, 1000 pairs loading to a dictionary or collection object should be a trivially insignificant amount of time.

Comment: Populating 1000 item dictionary with random values took less than .3 seconds.

Comment: @DavidZemens I have tested it with Outlook and it took over 10 seconds. The word pairs are stored in an Excel file so I guess it's actually loading them from the hard disk but not directly from the memory. Is it possible to make the pairs stay in the memory (even if no Office applications are running) for fast loading?

Comment: Can I see the code you are currently using to extract them from Excel? There's probably room to optimize it.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for your patience. I have had my current code added. When adding it, it occurred to me that it might be much faster by reading the values into an array all in once by something like `DataRange = Range(“A1:C10000″).Value` mentioned [here](http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/). I will try that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have a few observations that I will put in an answer for now (they are too long to fit in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

A few immediate observations... I don't know if these will be enough to make a significant difference in the time it takes to run this procedure with your file, but it may be worth a shot.

`CreateObject` I believe is faster than `New`.  Also, I notice you are `ReDimming` an array as `key_term`, and while you are assigning values to that array, you're never actually doing anything with it.  So that part seems like it is a duplicate effort, and can be removed. Further, I don't think you need to refer to the `.Item` with the dictionary, so let's try this:

```
Dim exlapp as Excel.Application

Set exlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

exlapp.Workbooks.Open FileName:=lexicon, ReadOnly:=True

Set oDic_term = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With exlapp.Workbooks(lexiconfile).Worksheets("Word Pairs")

    term_num = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = .UsedRange.Row To (.UsedRange.Row + term_num - 1)

        oDic_term(.Range("A" & i).Value) = .Range("B" & i).Value

    Next

End With
```

Most of the time spent is probably during the `New Excel.Application` or `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

You may look at other ways to query data from closed workbooks like ADODB. This should be much faster but will require knowing the size of the range you want to query, rather than using Excel to determine the `.UsedRange` or other method of finding the "last" row in the worksheet.

```
Sub test()

    Dim oDic_term As Object

    Dim lexiconFile As String

    lexiconFile = "c:\users\david_zemens\desktop\word pairs.xlsx"

    Set oDic_term = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Call GetData(lexiconFile, "Word Pairs", "A1:B1000", oDic_term, False, False)

End Sub
```

The above calls on this function that I have modified from Ron de Bruin.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm

```
Option Explicit
'REQUIRES REFERENCE TO EXCEL

Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, ByRef dict As Object, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
'Modified by David Zemens - 6 October 2014
' to return a Dictionary object of a two-column range key/value pair.

    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    ' Create the connection string.
    If Header = False Then
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
        End If
    Else
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        End If
    End If

    If SourceSheet = "" Then
        ' workbook level name
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
    Else
        ' worksheet level name or range
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
    End If

    On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
    If Not rsData.EOF Then

        Do While Not rsData.EOF
            dict(rsData.Fields(0).Value) = rsData.Fields(1).Value
            rsData.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up our Recordset object.
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close
    Set rsCon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```